# How to implement a constructor so it only accepts input iterators using typeid?

Tags: c++, constructor, iterator, c++14, sfinae

I want to implement a range constructor for a certain object, but I want to restrict it to only accept two input iterators.

I've tried to compile this code with gcc 7.1.0.

File `test.cpp`

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename Iterator>
using traits = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category;

template <typename T>
class A{
   private:

      std::vector<T> v;

   public:

      template <typename InputIterator,
               typename = std::enable_if_t<
                  typeid(traits<InputIterator>) ==
                  typeid(std::input_iterator_tag)>
               >
      A(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) : v(first, last) {}
};

int main(){
   std::vector<double> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   A<double> a(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

I get this compilation error with `g++ test.cpp -o test`:

```
  test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
  test.cpp:27:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘A<double>::A(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator)’
      A<double> a(v.begin(), v.end());
                                    ^
  test.cpp:22:7: note: candidate: template<class InputIterator, class> A<T>::A(InputIterator, InputIterator)
         A(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) : v(first, last) {}
         ^
  test.cpp:22:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
  test.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = ((const std::type_info*)(& _ZTISt26random_access_iterator_tag))->std::type_info::operator==(_ZTISt18input_iterator_tag); _Tp = void]’:
  test.cpp:18:16:   required from here
  test.cpp:19:49: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘bool std::type_info::operator==(const std::type_info&) const’
                     typeid(traits<InputIterator>) ==
  test.cpp:18:16: note: in template argument for type ‘bool’ 
                  typename = std::enable_if_t<
                  ^~~~~~~~
  test.cpp:10:7: note: candidate: A<double>::A(const A<double>&)
   class A{
         ^
  test.cpp:10:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
  test.cpp:10:7: note: candidate: A<double>::A(A<double>&&)
  test.cpp:10:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

I decided to use default template parameter because is more suitable for constructors. The use of the operator `typeid()` is because I find it really easy to read when mantaining the code, but I can't get it to work in any way.

Other solutions look very weird and are really obscure (like forcing the InputIterator parameter to have certain methods such as *it or ++it). If there's no way I can do this, I would appreciate a, more or less, easy-to-read solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do SFINAE you need to assure that evaluation of involving expressions happen at compile time. For [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) the following applies:

> When applied to an expression of polymorphic type, evaluation of a
>   typeid expression **may involve runtime overhead** (a virtual table
>   lookup), otherwise typeid expression is resolved at compile time.

Thus, I wouldn't consider `typeid` a good option for static (compile time) polymorphism.

One way you could solve your problem is by using tag dispatching in combination with a delegating costructor, as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
  std::vector<T> v;

  template <typename InputIterator>
  A(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, std::input_iterator_tag) : v(first, last) {}

public:

  template<typename InputIterator> A(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
  : A(first, last, typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::iterator_category()) {}
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20bcfbe39a41d64d)

Comment: I've never thought of this idea, which is really easy to understand and implement. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> The use of the operator `typeid()` is because I find it really easy to read when mantaining the code, but I can't get it to work in any way.

[`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) is a facility mainly used to query type information **at runtime**. While you might find it more "readable", it's not the right tool for the job and it will confuse every other C++ developer.

---

> Other solutions look very weird and are really obscure (like forcing the InputIterator parameter to have certain methods such as `*it` or `++it`)

I strongly advise you to reconsider this. An [`InputIterator` is a concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) that describers valid operations on a type. The whole idea behind a concept is checking for operation validity - there is nothing more than `InputIterator` than [its requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator).

The correct and idiomatic way of solving your issue is creating a `constexpr bool is_input_iterator<T>` variable/function that returns `true` if `T` matches `InputIterator`'s requirements. You can easily implement that using the [**detection idiom**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)... and it doesn't get more readable than `std::enable_if_t<is_input_iterator<T>>`.

Here a simplified example *(I'm not checking for all the requirements)*:

```
template <typename T>
using supports_increment = decltype(++std::declval<T>());

template <typename T>
using supports_dereference = decltype(*std::declval<T>());

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_input_iterator = 
    std::experimental::is_detected_v<supports_increment, T> 
 && std::experimental::is_detected_v<supports_dereference, T>;
```

```
  template <typename InputIterator,
           typename = std::enable_if_t<is_input_iterator<InputIterator>>>
  A(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) : v(first, last) {}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/svqOxV9QCZASHeDM)

Comment: Even though it looks a really elegant solution and express the idea of the concept of input iterator, I still struggle with all the stuff involving `decltype`. Also, I've never heard about **detection idiom**, which looks like it isn't in the standard yet (correct me if I'm wrong), and I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: There are many resources available online for free that explain how `decltype` and the detection idiom work. You can start here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1ekBpEFcPc

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to get into all the decltype world as soos as possible.